# Pushwoosh integration build error

Tags: ios, pushwoosh

I don't understand why I'm having this problem. Hope somebody can help me out on this one. I'm trying to import the pushwoosh framework, and having this strange error while building the project. All what I did was just drag&drop the framework from that folder SDK to my Frameworks folder and build the project. What's strange to me is that I couldn't find anybody else with this problem. I'm using the latest [pushwoosh SDK](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-ios-sdk), and tried multiple solutions for similar problems and nothing solved it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      pushwoosh::zipWriteInFileInZip(void*, void const*, unsigned int) in Pushwoosh(zip.o)
      pushwoosh::zipCloseFileInZipRaw(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) in Pushwoosh(zip.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      pushwoosh::unzReadCurrentFile(void*, void*, unsigned int) in Pushwoosh(unzip.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      pushwoosh::zipOpenNewFileInZip3(void*, char const*, pushwoosh::zip_fileinfo const*, void const*, unsigned int, void const*, unsigned int, char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, char const*, unsigned long) in Pushwoosh(zip.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      pushwoosh::zipCloseFileInZipRaw(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) in Pushwoosh(zip.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      pushwoosh::unzOpenCurrentFile3(void*, int*, int*, int, char const*) in Pushwoosh(unzip.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      pushwoosh::unzCloseCurrentFile(void*) in Pushwoosh(unzip.o)
  "_crc32", referenced from:
      -[PWZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in Pushwoosh(PWZipArchive.o)
      pushwoosh::unzReadCurrentFile(void*, void*, unsigned int) in Pushwoosh(unzip.o)
      pushwoosh::zipWriteInFileInZip(void*, void const*, unsigned int) in Pushwoosh(zip.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add libz.dylib to the project:

To do so:

go to target section
Build Phases tab
Link Binaries With Libraries
click on + button
search libz.dylib
clcik on add button.